# Click Jacking Vulnerability

Tags: .htaccess, click, clickjacking

I need a little guidance as I have a vulnerability in my apache webserver Click Jacking. In all the pages I have read I had to modify the htaccess but I do not find it on my server either VirtualHost and httpd.conf contains only comments not configuration so I do not know where this file is if it may not have it or if someone can help me with this problem, thank you!

Comment: You do not need `.htaccess` if you have access to the server config. (`.htaccess` is a per-directory Apache config file. You create it as needed. You may not have needed one.)

Comment: Where did you get that information from?
I am the same opinion my predecessor mentioned.
A countermeasure would be e.g. the X-Frame-Options header. Or in older non compatible Browsers you could use a framekiller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use X-Frame-Options to prevent your page from being loaded by frames.  This should prevent most clickjacking attacks.

You do this by setting `X-Frame-Options: DENY` in your header, or if you want to allow frames within your own site, you can set it to `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`.  If you want to whitelist a site, `try X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/`

Comment: Ok now I understand, I do not have to touch a global configuration file I only have to touch each Header of each webpage of the site, right?

Comment: @LorenzoSalazar Although the "global configuration file" is an obvious place to do that.

Comment: Thnks to all ;)

Comment: @LorenzoSalazar If this solved your issue, could you mark this answer as correct? Just click the little arrow beneath the votes.  Thanks :)

Comment: is not resolved, I'm still waiting for someone else to help me, thank you!